# How to access View control's from the ViewModel?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, mvvm, view, viewmodel

I've come across the situation, where I need access to the controls in the `View` from the `ViewModel`. In order to code a method that adds the selected item from a `ComboBox` to a list.

My question is how do I access the `View` controls from the `ViewModel`? Is there a certain design pattern I should follow to allow this?

The method below is coded in the `View's` code behind, which I know is bad practice if following the MVVM pattern, due to the tight coupling involved. Which is why I'm aiming to move this method the the `ViewModel`.

The method's purpose is to take the currently selected items from two `ComboBoxes` and add to a `Key/Value List`:

```
public void AddGradeSubjectChoiceToList()
{
    string SelectedSubjectName = "null data";
    int SelectedPoints = 01;


    SelectedSubjectName = subjectCmbBx.SelectedItem.ToString();

    try {

    SelectedPoints = int.Parse(ordinaryGradeCmbBx.SelectedValue.ToString());

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        //log error here..

    }

    List<StringKeyValue> SubjectPointKVTemp = new List<StringKeyValue>();

    //Add selected pair to list
    SubjectPointKVTemp.Add(new StringKeyValue { Key = SelectedSubjectName, Value = SelectedPoints });

    SubjectPointKV = SubjectPointKVTemp;
```

}

The XAML for the `MainPage` is set up like this, with two combo boxes, for subjects and grades. And the `addGrade` button which will call the method to add the selected pair to a list:

```
<Page x:Class="LC_Points.MainPage"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:Core="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core"
      xmlns:Interactivity="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity"
      xmlns:converter="using:LC_Points.Converter"
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
      xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"
      xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
      xmlns:local="using:LC_Points"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
      Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
      DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}}"
      mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Page.Resources>
        <converter:BoolToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVisibilityConverter" />
        <converter:BoolToNonVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToNonVisibilityConverter" />
    </Page.Resources>


    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="40*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="20*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="30*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="30*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="20*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="20*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="4*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="3*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


        <ComboBox x:Name="subjectCmbBx"
                  Grid.Row="1"
                  Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                  Width="174"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                  VerticalAlignment="Top"
                  DisplayMemberPath="Subject"
                  Header="Subjects"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Subjects}"
                  PlaceholderText="Pick a subject" />


        <ComboBox x:Name="ordinaryGradeCmbBx"
                  Grid.Row="1"
                  Grid.Column="0"
                  Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                  Width="170"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                  DisplayMemberPath="Key"
                  Header="Grades"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding OrdinaryGradePointKV}"
                  PlaceholderText="Pick a grade"
                  Visibility="{Binding IsHigherToggled,
                                       Mode=TwoWay,
                                       Converter={StaticResource BoolToNonVisibilityConverter}}" />


        <Button x:Name="addGradeBtn"
                Grid.Row="2"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                Command="{Binding Path=AddGradeCommand}"
                Content="Add Grade" />


        <ToggleButton x:Name="ordinaryTglBtn"
                      Grid.Row="3"
                      Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                      Content="Ordinary"
                      IsChecked="{Binding IsOrdinaryToggled,
                                          Mode=TwoWay}" />


    </Grid>


</Page>
```

The stripped down implementation of the `ViewModel` is as follows for reference, showing in comments how I pan to implement the `AddGradeSubjectChoiceToList()` method:

```
namespace LC_Points.ViewModel
{
    public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private ScoreModel _scoreModel;

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the MainViewModel class.
        /// </summary>
        public MainViewModel(ScoreModel GradeModel)
        {

            _scoreModel = GradeModel;

            //call methods to initilise list data
            GetSubjectTypes();
            GetOrdinaryGradePairs();
        }

        public List<ScoreModel> Subjects { get; set; }
        public List<StringKeyValue> OrdinaryGradePointKV { get; set; }

        //ordinary toggle button bool
        private bool _isOrdinaryToggled;
        public bool IsOrdinaryToggled
        {
            get
            {
                return _isOrdinaryToggled;
            }
            set
            {
                _isOrdinaryToggled = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("IsOrdinaryToggled");
            }
        }

        //Need to add same method from code behind to VM here
        //but don't have access to the View's controlsMethod to store Subject and Grade from Combo Boxes
        public void AddGradeSubjectChoiceToList()
        {

        }

        //This Relay Command is tied to the button in the View, that will be used
        //to call the AddGradeSubjectChoiceToList method
        RelayCommand addGradeCommand;
        public RelayCommand AddGradeCommand
        {
            get
            {
                if (addGradeCommand == null)
                {
                    addGradeCommand = new RelayCommand(() =>
                    {
                       AddGradeSubjectChoiceToList
                    });
                }
                return addGradeCommand;
            }
        }

        public class StringKeyValue
        {
            public string Key { get; set; }
            public int Value { get; set; }
        }

        public void GetOrdinaryGradePairs()
        {
            List<StringKeyValue> ordinaryGradePointKVTemp = new List<StringKeyValue>();


            ordinaryGradePointKVTemp.Add(new StringKeyValue { Key = "A1", Value = 60 });
            ordinaryGradePointKVTemp.Add(new StringKeyValue { Key = "A2", Value = 50 });
            ordinaryGradePointKVTemp.Add(new StringKeyValue { Key = "B1", Value = 45 });
            ordinaryGradePointKVTemp.Add(new StringKeyValue { Key = "B2", Value = 40 });
            ordinaryGradePointKVTemp.Add(new StringKeyValue { Key = "B3", Value = 35 });
            ordinaryGradePointKVTemp.Add(new StringKeyValue { Key = "C1", Value = 30 });
            ordinaryGradePointKVTemp.Add(new StringKeyValue { Key = "C2", Value = 25 });
            ordinaryGradePointKVTemp.Add(new StringKeyValue { Key = "C3", Value = 20 });


            OrdinaryGradePointKV = ordinaryGradePointKVTemp;

        }

        public void GetSubjectTypes()
        {
            List<ScoreModel> subjectList = new List<ScoreModel>();

            // Adding Subjects to List
            subjectList.Add(new ScoreModel { Subject = "Accounting" });
            subjectList.Add(new ScoreModel { Subject = "Agricultural Economics" });
            subjectList.Add(new ScoreModel { Subject = "Agricultural Science" });
            subjectList.Add(new ScoreModel { Subject = "Ancient Greek" });
            subjectList.Add(new ScoreModel { Subject = "Applied Math" });
            subjectList.Add(new ScoreModel { Subject = "Arabic" });
            subjectList.Add(new ScoreModel { Subject = "Art" });
            subjectList.Add(new ScoreModel { Subject = "Artistic & Creative Group" });
            subjectList.Add(new ScoreModel { Subject = "Biology" });
            subjectList.Add(new ScoreModel { Subject = "Business" });

            Subjects = subjectList;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please post the appropriate XAML-code?

Comment: Added the XAML above to the question.

Comment: You should bind each combo box's `SelectedItem` to the view model, not couple the view model to the view.

Comment: Any code example of that implementation? ^^

Comment: You don't send the UI to the ViewModel.  If you want to do that, just go ahead and do your work in the codebehind.  And if you can figure out how to bind to an ItemsSource property, you can bind to a SelectedItem property.  Same pattern.

Comment: Okay I get it now, I just need to bind the SelectedItem the same as I've set up the binding of ItemSource.

Comment: @BrianJ Yep, then at any point if you need to do something with that item, it's already available in the VM.

Comment: Will try that so, and see how I get on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to follow MVVM you should use generic types and bind them to the control.

Here's an example in one of my ViewModels:

```
private string[] _optionItems;
public string[] OptionItems
{
    get
    {
        return _optionItems;
    }
    set
    {
        if (_optionItems == value)
            return;

        _optionItems = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}

private string _selectedOption;
public string SelectedOption
{
    get
    {
        return _selectedOption;
    }
    set
    {
        if (_selectedOption == value)
            return;

        _selectedOption = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

and here's the XAML code:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding OptionItems}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedOption}"/>
```

Comment: Of course i used a string array for the collection. This works fine if you expect your list to remain static, otherwise I'd use an ObservableCollection<string>

Answer (score 1):

As the above comments point out, the solution of coupling the View to the ViewModel is bad practice when following the MVVM pattern.

The appropriate solution is to set up a property for the ComboBox's `SelectedItem` and bind the View to that, so that the Selected items are available for leveraging in the VM.

**1.** Set up binding to *SelectedItem* in the **View**:

```
SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSubject,Mode=TwoWay}"
```

**2.** Create the ComboBox property in the **ViewModel**:

```
        private ComboBox _selectedSubject;
        public ComboBox SelectedSubject
        {
            get { return _selectedSubject; }

            set
            {
                _selectedSubject = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedSubject");
            }
        }
```

Comment: This is still IMHO bad MVVM practice as you're still referencing a specific UI control type in your ViewModel. See my answer to a more generic approach.

Comment: There is a difference between data binding and manipulating the control.  For example, scrolling to a specific item in a collectionview programatically.  You have to do something like this. +1 @Brian Var.